# Seasonally adjust several series on R

Tags: r

I built a function to seasonally adjust Brazilian economic data, due to Carnival.

But this way, I can adjust only one series at a time, in my clipboard.

I've been trying, then, to adjust more series (copy several series one next to the other) but unsuccessfully.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

```
   seasbrasil<-function(y0,m0,yT,mT) {carnaval<-c(as.Date("2000-03-07"),as.Date("2001-02-27"),as.Date("2002-02-12"),as.Date("2003-03-04"),as.Date("2004-02-24"),as.Date("2005-02-08"),as.Date("2006-02-28"),as.Date("2007-02-20"),as.Date("2008-02-05"),as.Date("2009-02-24"),as.Date("2010-02-16"),as.Date("2011-03-08"),as.Date("2012-02-21"),as.Date("2013-02-12"),as.Date("2014-03-04"),as.Date("2015-02-17"),as.Date("2016-02-09"))
library(seasonal)
Sys.setenv(X13_PATH = "C:\\Users\\gfernandes\\Documents\\x13as")
checkX13()
data(holiday)
carnaval.ts <- genhol(carnaval, start = -1, end = 2, center = "calendar")
x <- read.table(file = "clipboard", sep = "\t", header=FALSE)
x <-ts(x,start=c(y0,m0),end=c(yT,mT),frequency=12)
xsa <-seas(x,xreg=carnaval.ts,regression.usertype="holiday",x11=list())
summary(xsa)
plot(xsa)
xsa<-final(xsa)
write.csv(xsa, file = "C:\\Users\\gfernandes\\Documents\\ajuste.csv")
getwd()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the clipboard to read data is not a scaleable solution instead would suggest
    creating a list of file names using `list.files` and applying your function on this list.

```
#Load all libraries first
library(seasonal)


#Define your data directory
DIR="C:\\path-to-your-dir\\"

#Replace .dat with  file extension applicable
# set recursive = TRUE if you have tree directory structure

TS_fileList <- list.files(path=DIR,pattern=".dat",full.names = TRUE,recursive=FALSE)



#define carnival dates
 carnaval<-c(
 "2000-03-07","2001-02-27","2002-02-12",
 "2003-03-04","2004-02-24","2005-02-08",
 "2006-02-28","2007-02-20","2008-02-05",
 "2009-02-24","2010-02-16","2011-03-08",
 "2012-02-21","2013-02-12","2014-03-04",
 "2015-02-17","2016-02-09")

#format carnival variable as date
carnaval <- as.Date(carnaval,format="%Y-%m-%d")

data(holiday)
carnaval.ts <- genhol(carnaval, start = -1, end = 2, center = "calendar")
```

**Function:**

```
 fn_adj_seasbrasil <-function(
 filePath = "C:\\path-to-your-dir\\file1.dat",
 carnivalTS = carnaval.ts,
 y0,
 m0,
 yT,
 mT) {

#moved few operations outside this function
#since they are common to all files
#instead now the carnival series is 
#input as parameter

x <- read.table(file = filePath, sep = "\t", header=FALSE)
x <- ts(x,start=c(y0,m0),end=c(yT,mT),frequency=12)
xsa <-seas(x,xreg = carnivalTS,regression.usertype="holiday",x11=list())
summary(xsa)
plot(xsa)
xsa<-final(xsa)

#save seasonally adjusted file with different suffix
fileName = tail(unlist(strsplit(filePath,sep="/")),1)
suffix = "adjuste"

#for adjusted time series of file1.dat 
# the name will be adjuste_file1.dat
newFilePath = head(unlist(strsplit(filePath,sep="/")),1)
newFileName = paste0(newFilePath,"/",suffix,"_",fileName)

write.csv(xsa, file = newFileName)

cat(paste0("Saved file:",newFileName,"\n"))

}

#define y0,m0,yT,mT and then for all files call the function

lapply(TS_fileList,function(x) fn_adj_seasbrasil(filePath = x,carnivalTS = carnaval.ts, y0,m0,yT,mT) )
```

This might not work for your in first pass but can be resolved by familiarising yourself
    with tutorials like these [ATS UCLA](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/modules/) and also reading
    function help of `?read.table`,`?list.files` , `?strsplit` etc.